# jquery update the anchor tag's image src based on query string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I replace the image src on each of the elements?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userShop">
  <p class="shoppingbaskets">
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=empty"><img src="image/empty.png" title="empty" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=full"><img src="image/full.png" title="full" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=semi"><img src="image/semi.png" title="semi" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=abandoned"><img src="image/abandoned.png" title="abandoned" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=completed"><img src="image/completed.png" title="completed" width="50" height="50"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to replace the img src based on the query string `basket` value.
For example, if it is `empty`, then its image src will be `newDir/newImageEmpty.jpg`

here is my attempt:

```
var listStatus = [
    {
       'name': 'full',
       'image': 'http://www.faredelbene.net/img/icon_stumble.png'
    },
    // and some more for others

];

listStatus.forEach(function (item){
    $("#userShop a").each(function(link) {
  if (item.name.indexOf(
       new URL(this.href).searchParams.get("basket")
     ) !=-1) {
    $(this).find("img").attr({src: item.image});
  }
});
})
```

is this the correct approach?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, in reality,

you should be able to do it just with some research on Google, but ah well.

---

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

console.log("Src before: " + $('#emptyImage').attr('src'));

// Iterate over all links
links.forEach((el) => {
  // Get index of 'empty' in string if exists
  if (el.search.indexOf('empty') !== -1) {
    // Modify src to new src
    $(el).find('img').attr("src", "newDir/newImageEmpty.jpg");
  }
});

console.log("Src after: " + $('#emptyImage').attr('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userShop">
  <p class="shoppingbaskets">
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=empty"><img id="emptyImage" src="image/empty.png" title="empty" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=full"><img src="image/full.png" title="full" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=semi"><img src="image/semi.png" title="semi" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=abandoned"><img src="image/abandoned.png" title="abandoned" width="50" height="50"></a>
    <a href="RunFunction.jsp;jsessionid=123456789?shop=querty&basket=completed"><img src="image/completed.png" title="completed" width="50" height="50"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```